# Perform math using multiple changing SELECT results

Tags: sql, t-sql

To start, I have looked at the other questions with similar titles and they are not of help to me.

My issue: I need to perform a percentage calculation based upon result sets associated with specific dates.  The dates are not fixed and there are several of them.  The calculations need to be repeated for a 12 month cycle starting from the retrieved date.  Each date must be treated independently of the rest.  When working with one specified date, my query executes as expected.  Having to work with multiple dates is where my problems begin.

An example of how my query works if it knows the exact date (only a 3 month portion of the query is shown):

```
    DECLARE @StartDate as date,
    @Customer as varchar(7),
    @TotalPlaced as money

    SET @StartDate = '2018-01-04'
    SET @Customer = '0000054'
    SET @TotalPlaced = (SELECT SUM(original) FROM master with (nolock) WHERE 
    customer = @Customer AND received = @StartDate)


    SELECT (SUM(gross)/@TotalPlaced)*100
    FROM PAYMENTS with (nolock)
    WHERE customer = @Customer
    AND received = @StartDate
    AND entered between @StartDate and (SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, 
    DATEDIFF(m,0,@StartDate)+1,0)))


    SELECT (SUM(gross)/@TotalPlaced)*100
    FROM PAYMENTS with (nolock)
    WHERE customer = @Customer
    AND received = @StartDate
    AND entered between (SELECT DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @StartDate)+1, 0)) 
    AND (SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@StartDate)+2,0)))


    SELECT (SUM(gross)/@TotalPlaced)*100
    FROM PAYMENTS with (nolock)
    WHERE customer = @Customer
    AND received = @StartDate
    AND entered between (SELECT DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @StartDate)+2, 0)) 
    AND (SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@StartDate)+3,0)))
```

This will yield the result set:

```
    1.00
    0.17
    0.15
```

Now if I change the query a little bit to look for any date after the specified date and group by those dates, the math calculations are incorrect and the query doesn't treat the date values independently.  Example:

```
    DECLARE @StartDate as date,
    @TotalPlaced as money
    SET @StartDate = '2018-01-04'
    SET @TotalPlaced = (SELECT SUM(original) FROM master with (nolock) WHERE 
    customer = '0000054'AND received = @StartDate)



    SELECT received, (SUM(gross)/@TotalPlaced)*100
    FROM PAYMENTS with (nolock)
    WHERE customer = '0000054'
    AND received >= @StartDate
    AND entered between @StartDate and (SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, 
    DATEDIFF(m,0,@StartDate)+1,0)))
    GROUP BY received
    ORDER BY received


    SELECT received, (SUM(gross)/@TotalPlaced)*100
    FROM PAYMENTS with (nolock)
    WHERE customer = '0000054'
    AND received >= @StartDate
    AND entered between (SELECT DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @StartDate)+1, 0)) 
    AND (SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@StartDate)+2,0)))
    GROUP BY received
    ORDER BY received


    SELECT received, (SUM(gross)/@TotalPlaced)*100
    FROM PAYMENTS with (nolock)
    WHERE customer = '0000054'
    AND received >= @StartDate
    AND entered between (SELECT DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @StartDate)+2, 0)) 
    AND (SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@StartDate)+3,0)))
    GROUP BY received
    ORDER BY received
```

Done this way it seems the values for the dates become intermingled, and it also does not treat the dates completely separately as I need it to.  Instead of a 12 month result set for each date, the query now only includes calculations starting from the month associated with the date ('2018-03-02' will begin showing results in month 3 '2018-04-03' will begin showing results in month 4, when they should be showing starting month 1) and the actual math is wrong too, for example the result for 2018-04-03 should be 0.77

```
    received    percentage
    2018-01-04  0.17
    2018-03-02  0.05
    2018-04-03  18.08
```

From here I tried to do a WHILE loop figuring this would give the independence I need.

```
    DECLARE @StartDate as date,
    @Customer as varchar(7),
    @TotalPlaced as money

    SET @StartDate = '2018-01-04'
    SET @Customer = '0000054'
    SET @TotalPlaced = (SELECT SUM(original) FROM master with (nolock) WHERE 
    customer = @Customer AND received = @StartDate)


    CREATE TABLE #Totals
    (ReceivedDate date,
    Processed int null,
    M1 varchar(15) null,
    M2 varchar(15) null,
    M3 varchar(15) null)


    INSERT INTO #Totals
    SELECT distinct(received), 1, null, null, null
    FROM master with (nolock)
    WHERE customer = @Customer
    AND received >= @StartDate

    --VARIABLES FOR LOOP
    DECLARE @CHKDATE date = ''  
    DECLARE @RECORDCOUNT int = (SELECT COUNT(ReceivedDate) FROM #Totals)


    --LOOP SYNTAX
    WHILE (@RECORDCOUNT > 0)    
    BEGIN       

    SELECT top 1 @CHKDATE = (SELECT MIN(ReceivedDate) FROM #Totals WHERE 
    Processed = 1)
    FROM #Totals
    WHERE processed = 1

     IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BREAK;

        UPDATE #Totals SET M1 =   
        (SELECT (SUM(gross)/@TotalPlaced)*100
        FROM PAYMENTS with (nolock)
        WHERE customer = '0000054'
        AND received = @CHKDATE
        AND entered between @CHKDATE and (SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, 
     DATEDIFF(m,0,@CHKDATE)+1,0))))


        UPDATE #Totals SET M2 =
        (SELECT (SUM(gross)/@TotalPlaced)*100
        FROM PAYMENTS with (nolock)
        WHERE customer = '0000054'
        AND received = @CHKDATE
        AND entered between (SELECT DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @CHKDATE)+1, 
     0)) and (SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@CHKDATE)+2,0))))


        UPDATE #Totals SET M3 =
        (SELECT (SUM(gross)/@TotalPlaced)*100
        FROM PAYMENTS with (nolock)
        WHERE customer = '0000054'
        AND received = @CHKDATE
        AND entered between (SELECT DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @CHKDATE)+2, 
     0)) and (SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@CHKDATE)+3,0))))


        UPDATE #Totals SET  processed = 0  WHERE ReceivedDate = @CHKDATE
        SET @RECORDCOUNT = @RECORDCOUNT - 1

        END
```

Still the results are wrong.

```
    ReceivedDate    Processed   M1      M2      M3
    2018-01-04      0           0.49    0.95    0.54
    2018-02-02      0           0.49    0.95    0.54
    2018-03-02      0           0.49    0.95    0.54
    2018-04-03      0           0.49    0.95    0.54
    2018-05-02      0           0.49    0.95    0.54
    2018-06-06      0           0.49    0.95    0.54
    2018-07-05      0           0.49    0.95    0.54
```

I could use help seeing where I have gone wrong with the loop, or any suggestions as to how I can achieve the desired results.  The picture below is what my overall report should look like.  All the rest of the query works fine, it's just this last part I'm hung up on.

[image: What my overall report should look like]

Comment: don't use loops in sql -- that is never a solution.  What is the grouping you want?

Comment: @hogan I know loops aren't a best practice.  I just couldn't think of another way.  For this report, a user needs to be able to specify a client and a starting date.  The query then finds all business batch receive dates after that date.  The result sets should be grouped based upon the receive date for each batch of business. but each date needs to be treated independent of the rest.  I hope I'm explaining that well enough.

Comment: you are not explaining -- I got that but what is the size of the period you are grouping -- 1 month -- 1 year ?  and I understand you can't think of another way... sql is hard you have to *think* in sets

Comment: @Hogan sorry I didn't understand the question.  As I said in the post, it is monthly, but not as in calendar month.  I'm not looking for January February etc, just 12 months, month by month, from the receive date.  If you look at the portion of the query I provided you'll notice that each one advances one month out from the last, starting from the receive date.  I didn't post the full 12 month query.  I figured 3 months was enough to demonstrate how it is written.

Comment: so you want startdate + 12 months?  got it.   I think you just have to add @startdate to the group by statement.  GROUP BY received, `@startdate`

Comment: @Hogan unfortunately that did not work.  It generated an error:  "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference."  I tried doing it a few different ways, but no go.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the data model -- I'd need to see example data and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of days of breaking down the query to its smaller parts I discovered the problem.  The loop variables were not being refreshed at each iteration through the loop.  I also changed the iteration method slightly by setting up a temp table of the records needing processing, and then deleting each record as it is processed through the loop.  Here is the revised syntax should anyone else find they need help with a similar WHILE loop:

```
    ---------------------Create temp tables for WHILE Loop


    CREATE TABLE #LoopTemp
    (ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) primary key,
    ReceivedDate date)

    CREATE TABLE #LoopTotals
    (ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) primary key,
    ReceivedDate date,
    M1 varchar(15) null,
    M2 varchar(15) null,
    M3 varchar(15) null,
    M4 varchar(15) null)


    ------------------------Populate #LoopTemp with receive dates

    INSERT INTO #LoopTemp
    SELECT distinct(received)
    FROM master with (nolock)
    WHERE customer = @Customer
    AND received >= @StartDate




    --------VARIABLES FOR LOOP
    DECLARE @CHKDATE date = ''  
    DECLARE @RECORDCOUNT int = (SELECT COUNT(ReceivedDate) FROM #LoopTemp)
    DECLARE @PKID int
    DECLARE @TotalPlaced as money


    -------LOOP SYNTAX
    WHILE (@RECORDCOUNT > 0)    
    BEGIN       

    SELECT @PKID = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM #LoopTemp)
    SELECT @CHKDATE = (SELECT MIN(ReceivedDate) FROM #LoopTemp WHERE ID = @PKID)
    SET @TotalPlaced = (SELECT SUM(original) FROM master with (nolock) WHERE customer 
    = @Customer AND received = @CHKDATE)


     IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BREAK;

        INSERT INTO #LoopTotals SELECT @CHKDATE 
        ((SUM(gross)/@TotalPlaced)*100),null,null,null,null
        FROM PAYMENTS with (nolock)
        WHERE customer = @Customer
        AND received = @CHKDATE
        AND entered between @CHKDATE and (SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, 
        DATEDIFF(m,0,@CHKDATE)+1,0)))


        UPDATE #LoopTotals SET M2 =
        (SELECT (SUM(gross)/@TotalPlaced)*100
        FROM PAYMENTS with (nolock)
        WHERE customer = @Customer
        AND received = @CHKDATE
        AND entered between (SELECT DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @CHKDATE)+1, 0)) and 
        (SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@CHKDATE)+2,0))))
        WHERE ReceivedDate = @CHKDATE
        AND ID = @PKID


        UPDATE #LoopTotals SET M3 =
        (SELECT (SUM(gross)/@TotalPlaced)*100
        FROM PAYMENTS with (nolock)
        WHERE customer = @Customer
        AND received = @CHKDATE
        AND entered between (SELECT DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @CHKDATE)+2, 0)) and 
        (SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@CHKDATE)+3,0))))
        WHERE ReceivedDate = @CHKDATE
        AND ID = @PKID


        UPDATE #LoopTotals SET M4 =
        (SELECT (SUM(gross)/@TotalPlaced)*100
        FROM PAYMENTS with (nolock)
        WHERE customer = @Customer
        AND received = @CHKDATE
        AND entered between (SELECT DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @CHKDATE)+3, 0)) and 
        (SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@CHKDATE)+4,0))))
        WHERE ReceivedDate = @CHKDATE
        AND ID = @PKID


        --Advance loop to next record by deleting the record just ran
        DELETE FROM #LoopTemp WHERE ReceivedDate = @CHKDATE
        SET @RECORDCOUNT = @RECORDCOUNT - 1



        END
```